# How to use variable method names

Tags: symfony, variables, twig

I have 5 methods in my Methods entity:

```
method1
method2
method3
method4
method5
```

My goal is to randomly generate a table with those 5 methods.
For that, I have an array with numbers from 1 to 5, example

```
array(1,3,5,4,2);
```

Then, when generating my table in the twig file, I would like to call:

```
<td>methods.method<array[0]></td>
<td>methods.method<array[1]></td>
....
```

So that the real methods called would be

```
<td>methods.method1></td>
<td>methods.method3></td>
....
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: If you name methods like `methodN` i suggest to you change them

Comment: @DonCallisto, my methods are named methodN, what's the problem thre. I can alos name them methodOne etc, but this will not change my issue.

Comment: No, this doesn't change anything but a method name should be properly named. Just an annotation that I would like to give. Nevermind.

Comment: @DonCallisto, I see. This was here an example, for an ease of understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fond the solution: Use of the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

```
 attribute(methods, 'method'~array[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement a new method:

```
function callMethod(int $method_number){
    return $this->'method'.$method_number;

}
```

then on twig:

```
... {{ object.callMethod(random_number)  }} ...
```